# Put last polynomdivision at the end

Tags: displaystyle, polynom

I'm trying to explain the polynom division step whise so I'm using the `polynom` package for that. Now if I just want to show the beginning of the polynom division this pops up:

[image]

And here's the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrartcl}

% =============
% Packages 
% =============
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                % west european chars
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}   % math symbols
\usepackage{polynom}

\begin{document}
\polylongdiv[stage=1, style=C, div=:]{x^2}{x + 1}
\end{document}
```

As you can see I set `stage` to 1 but the fraction is still displayed! How can I hide it? Because in the next line I increase stage step by step and it's a little bit "weird" if you can see the fraction already in the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be standard for style C. You can see at http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/polynom/polydemo.pdf how the other styles look and perhaps one of the others is more to your liking (style A is how I always taught polynomial long division).

Comment: In school we are doing the polynomial division like in style C. I wasn't even aware that there are multiple types of polynomial division.

Comment: It's all the same polynomial division, it's just different ways to organize the information.